# Why one structure inside another is updated and second not?

Tags: c, structure

I want to update both date and time structures. I am using the example from programming 4th edition by Stephen Kochan:

"Write a function called clockKeeper() that takes as its argument a dateAndTime structure as defined in this chapter. The function should call the timeUpdate() function, and if the time reaches midnight, the function should call the dateUpdate function to switch over to the next day. Have the function return the updated dateAndTime structure. "

This is a learning process for me and it seems that I do not fully understand how to use structures, can anyone show me where the problem is and provide a brief explanation? The program always updates the time, but date stays the same, I've tried to make changes but no matter what I do it gives me a compile error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//does not work properly issues with - the date update
//Program to update date and time

struct time timeUpdate (struct time now);
struct date dateUpdate (struct date today);
struct dateAndTime  clockKeeper (struct dateAndTime  dt);

struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

struct time
{
    int hour;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
};

struct dateAndTime 
{
    struct date   sdate;
    struct time   stime; 
};

struct dateAndTime  dt1 =
     {
         { 1, 11, 19 }, { 00, 00, 00 }
     };

bool  isLeapYear (struct date  d);
int  numberOfDays  (struct date  d);
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf ("Current date and time is %.2i/%.2i/%.2i "
        "%.2i:%.2i:%.2i\n",
        dt1.sdate.month, dt1.sdate.day, dt1.sdate.year,
        dt1.stime.hour, dt1.stime.minutes, dt1.stime.seconds);

    dt1 = clockKeeper (dt1);

    printf ("Updated date and time is %.2i/%.2i/%.2i "
        "%.2i:%.2i:%.2i\n\n", 
        dt1.sdate.month, dt1.sdate.day, dt1.sdate.year,
        dt1.stime.hour, dt1.stime.minutes, dt1.stime.seconds);
}

struct dateAndTime  clockKeeper (struct dateAndTime  dt)
{
     struct time  timeUpdate (struct time  now);
     struct date  dateUpdate (struct date  today);

     dt.stime = timeUpdate (dt.stime);
//looks like this is not working :(
    if ( dt.stime.hour == 0  &&  dt.stime.minutes == 0  &&
             dt.stime.seconds == 0 )
         dt.sdate = dateUpdate (dt.sdate);

        return  dt;
}

  //counting time
struct time timeUpdate (struct time now)
{
    ++now.seconds;

    if (now.seconds == 60 ) 
    {
            now.seconds = 0;
        ++now.minutes;
    }
        if( now.minutes == 60) 
        {

            now.minutes = 0;
            ++now.hour;
        }
            if( now.hour == 24) 
            {

                now.hour = 0;

            }



return now;
}

struct date dateUpdate (struct date today)
{
    struct date tomorrow;
    int numberOfDays (struct date d);

    if(today.day != numberOfDays (today))
    {
        tomorrow.day = today.day +1;
        tomorrow.month = today.month;
        tomorrow.year = today.year;
    }

    else if(today.month == 12) //end of year
    {
        tomorrow.day = 1;
        tomorrow.month = 1;
        tomorrow.year = today.year + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        tomorrow.day = 1;
        tomorrow.month = today.month + 1;
        tomorrow.year = today.year;
    }
    return tomorrow;
}

// Function to find the number of days in a month

 int  numberOfDays  (struct date  d)
{
      int days;
      bool  isLeapYear (struct date  d);

      const int   daysPerMonth[12] ={ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

      if ( isLeapYear (d) == true &&  d.month == 2 )days = 29;
       else
           days = daysPerMonth[d.month - 1];

    return days; 
} 

bool  isLeapYear (struct date  d) 

{

bool  leapYearFlag;
    if ( (d.year % 4 == 0  &&  d.year % 100 != 0)  ||d.year % 400 == 0 )
        leapYearFlag = true;   // It's a leap year

        else

        leapYearFlag = false;  // Not a leap year

return leapYearFlag; 
}
```

Current result: 
Current date and time is 01/11/19 00:00:00
Updated date and time is 01/11/19 00:00:01

I expect the date to be updated too.

Comment: C passes arguments to functions *by value!* That means the values are *copied* into the argument variables. And if you modify a copy, then the original value will not be modified. To solve your problem, please do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude as I see there is no supposed input-output parameter, the code always use the return value and this is ok.

Comment: Note that the `struct date` in the function prototype is unrelated to the `struct date` defined later in the code shown.  A decent compiler would give you warnings about that.  Either include three lines like `struct date;` before the prototypes, or place the prototypes after the structure definitions.  Under normal circumstances, what you show won't compile — so if you're getting runtime problems, what you're running isn't what you show.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `gcc -Wall -pedantic` signals nothing, nor `g++ -Wall -pedantic`, where do you see a problem ?

Comment: @bruno: Curious, but yes: you're right (mea culpa).  The reason is that the code has `struct time timeUpdate(struct time now);` which means that `struct time` is announced to the world before the argument list (as the return type).  I didn't notice that the return type was the same as the argument type.  If the function returned something else, then you'd get the warning: if the first function declaration was `void timeUpdate(struct time *now);` for example, you'd get the warning I was expecting.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler hehe, except when the given code is very small I first always compile with warning options, the compiler looks better than our eyes ^^

Comment: @bruno — I often use the compiler to test too. I thought I'd spotted a problem, because I (thought I) recognized a problem pattern.  I hadn't previously seen the get-out-of-jail-free card that this code uses; I'll remember it for the future.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in fact the code works perfectly

Comment: You don't need to keep repeating the function declarations inside functions.  Indeed, it is better not to declare functions inside other functions; it makes it hard to keep things consistent, especially if the function being declared is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you saying your code does not work ? For me it works well

One second after `01/11/19 00:00:00` it is `01/11/19 00:00:01`, the day doesn't have to change

if I change the initial time having :

```
struct dateAndTime  dt1 =
 {
     { 1, 11, 19 }, { 23, 59, 59 }
 };
```

that gives :

```
Current date and time is 01/11/19 23:59:59
Updated date and time is 01/12/19 00:00:00
```

and the date changed well as the time

---

As Jonathan Leffler says in a remark remove the declaration of functions into the functions

in *clockKeeper* remove the lines

```
  struct time  timeUpdate (struct time  now);
  struct date  dateUpdate (struct date  today);
```

and in *dateUpdate* remove the line

```
int numberOfDays (struct date d);
```

You already declared the functions at the top of the file

Comment: omg, you are correct, I looked so much in the code that I did not notice the incorrect input...  thank you all for the suggestions and on how to write clean code! Regards, PT